# Storing images and getting them from a website and an android application

Tags: php, android, server, retrofit2, web-hosting

I have done a simple gallery app in Android Studio and then made a gallery website using the same database to show the same content as my gallery app. I am using my pc as a server with XAMPP and everything works.

The thing is, now **I don't want to use my pc as a server and I'd like to upload my webpage to some free hosting like 000webhost to share it with my friends and other people because I really don't want to leave my computer on 24/7**. I also want the data accessible from my app to read and write as it does now but on a real server. I just don't know how to do it (I've used 000webhost before but I***think*** it works for the website only, I mean, I can show the images stored there from my app but I can't upload new images from my app).

I don't know if it's the import but, I've used retrofit to connect my app to my database and server.

I'm still a student, I don't know a lot about this stuff but I want to learn, I'd be grateful if you could help me here.

Comment: get the url of the image(where your image is stored) and display in android app via library like Glide or Picasso. and to upload image you can convert the image into base64 string and send it to your host and using backend script you can write image in your host location.**AND PLEASE NOTE- DON'T USE YOUR WEB ADDRESS to store image.(ex. www.000webhost.app.yourwebsitename)**. you need to provide actual path

Comment: and 000webhost is fine option, you can use it to store your images and some back end script. I am using the same and using for the same purpose (to upload image), so it won't be an issue.

Comment: Hi Sam, I really appreciate you help. How can I upload images to my public_html folder from my app? How can I do it without been me dragging the new content to the root folder?

Comment: ahh, its a long process. i cannot explain all in comments. I did it using the PHP as backend which i uploaded in 000webhost, and call that service from android when i need to upload an image.And please not -  Since there will be multiple image, and you need to give permission to write data in order to upload, make a new folder inside public_html called "Image" and give Write Permission to that folder.

Comment: here is the tutorial - [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8IBhHRUu3eM) and do check his website if you need further help.

Comment: After a long search I finally made it, thank you a lot, I used Apache Commons Net